# How to reduce or remove the initial pause while scrolling the webpage using arrow keys

Tags: keyboard, browser, scrolling, frontend

When I press and hold the down arrow key to scroll any webpage it initially scrolls a little and pauses for a moment before it actually starts scrolling smoothly. Want to know if there is any workaround or a setting to remove this initial pause. The Issue is occuring on both windows and MAC on all browsers. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The feature is known as "keyboard repeat delay" and it is the gap in time after you hold the key down before it starts repeating. It is intended to help avoid the key repeating when it is not wanted.

In Windows there are a few ways to adjust it [such as via the "old" control panel](https://winaero.com/change-keyboard-repeat-delay-and-rate-in-windows-10/) by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and in the run dialog typing `control keyboard`, or [via the registry](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/difference-between-key-repeat-rate-and-repeat-delay).

[On Macs](https://www.google.com/search?&q=keyboard%20repeat%20delay%20mac) the settings are found under [System Preferences Keyboard Settings](http://howto.academyart.edu/accessibility/keyboard-and-mouse-difficulties/make-your-keyboard-easier-to-use/keyboard-settings-mac)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the other answer is that it affects everything rather than just up/down arrow key scrolling in the browser.

I use this Chrome extension to remove the delay:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smooth-key-scroll/gphmhpfbknciemgfnfhjapilmcaecljh

It works very well.